# How can I list files in a loop in unix

Tags: unix

I have a collection of files like *_100_flank.fasta *_200_flank.fasta etc etc

When I try
`ls *_100_flank.fasta` I get the extpected output

when I try:

```
for i in `seq 100 100 200`; do ls *_$i_flank.fasta; done
```

I get: No such file or directory..

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried it and it worked fine. `$ touch dad_200.fasta doo_200.fasta touch foo_100.fasta touch bar_100.fasta touch dad_200.fasta`. Then ran your command and got the expected
`bar_100.fasta foo_100.fasta
dad_200.fasta doo_200.fasta`

Comment: this produces *_.fasta, I think the underscore is doing something funny?

Comment: Hmm, your exact line works as expected in my bash.

Comment: Maybe you put it in a script and forgot to `chmod +x` ... just a guess...

Answer (score 0):

the answer is that I needed to escape the final underscore (didn't realise this was important hence not in the original question sorry):

```
for i in `seq 100 100 200`; do ls *_$i\_flank.fasta; done
```